# How to return data to a object as response in a function argument (as that of jquery ui autocomplete )

Tags: jquery

Jquery UI source method

```
source : function(request, response) { response (/*some data*/)}
```

My code is as follows

```
$.fn.foo = function(uri){
  return this.each(function(){
    var _response;
    //get that 'response' using source method      
    //and assign it (response) to a variable say '_response'
   //$.fn.foo.methods.source.call($this[0], uri) can be used if possible to get that

  });
}

$.fn.foo.methods {
  source: function(uri, response) {
   $.get(uri, function(data){
      //maybe as
      response(data);
   });
  }
}
```

Please help me,
I just can't exporting the data got from `$.get(uri, function(data){})` to a local variable

Comment: this.methods.source() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a synchronous `GET` request.

```
$.fn.foo.methods {
  source: function(uri, response) {
    var result;
    $.ajax({
      url: uri,
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
        result = data;
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
}
```

EDIT:

In case you want to use a callback method, you can do something along the lines of the following. But note that this is now **asynchronous**.

```
$.fn.foo = function(uri){
  return this.each(function() {
    $.fn.foo.methods.source.call($this[0], uri, function (data) {
      // Do something with the data asynchronously, once the request has returned
    });
  });
}

$.fn.foo.methods {
  source: function(uri, response) {
   $.get(uri, response);
  }
}
```

Comment: I know this method but i want to use response(data); method

Comment: In that case `response` has to be a callback method.